# The link inside the card description should lead to the site, but it closes the description

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, click

There is [code for the card](https://codepen.io/alivim/pen/QWwBENZ) that I want to use on my page, but I need the "Read more" link to lead to another page and not close the description of the card. Unfortunately, I am not strong in jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var zindex = 10;

  $("div.card").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var isShowing = false;
    if ($(this).hasClass("show")) {
      isShowing = true
    }

    if ($("div.cards").hasClass("showing")) {
      // a card is already in view
      $("div.card.show").removeClass("show");

      if (isShowing) {
        // this card was showing - reset the grid
        $("div.cards").removeClass("showing");
      } else {
        // this card isn't showing - get in with it
        $(this).css({
          zIndex: zindex
        }).addClass("show");
      }
      zindex++;
    } else {
      // no cards in view
      $("div.cards").addClass("showing");
      $(this).css({
        zIndex: zindex
      }).addClass("show");
      zindex++;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card__image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/300x225/?wave" alt="wave" />
    <div class="card-title">
      <a href="#" class="toggle-info btn">
        <span class="left"></span>
        <span class="right"></span>
      </a>
      <h2>
        Card title
        <small>Image from unsplash.com</small>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card-flap flap1">
      <div class="card-description">
        This grid is an attempt to make something nice that works on touch devices. Ignoring hover states when they're not available etc.
      </div>
      <div class="card-flap flap2">
        <div class="card-actions">
          <a href="https://www.behance.net/gallery/72373861/BBDO-Ecuador" class="btn">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cant you add the link to your page in the href `<a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>` ?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I added, but it doesn't work. When you click on the link "Read more" the description of the card is closed, and not lead to the page where I need it. That's why I asked for help

Answer (score 0):

first remove preventDefault()

```
 $("div.card").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); <-- remove this line
```

and add link to the button

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="btn">Read more</a>
```

Comment: If I remove this line, the action button returns me to the top of the page. And the link "Read more" still does not work. only It closes description